# Package manager and app manager in embedded linux using C++

Tags: c++, embedded-linux, package-managers, app-manager

I am looking for package manager and App manager implementation using c++ on embedded linux with
consideration of app manager scenario (run/pause/resume/exit/recovery) with below packaging features.

(1) installation of package

(2) uninstallation of package

(3) package factory reset

(3) package integrity check

I have considered **ipkg , opkg, conan and dpkg** packages but those are very heavy and can't be considered on embedded linux device . So It looks like I need to implement my own pakcage manager which will do packaging by copying binary ,resource and configuration files to a package directory and after that need to calculate the checksum for file integrity ( using sha256) so that during uninstallation of package same can be achieved by verifying the checksum of package and after that need to implement package signing . So thought to discuss if any library I can use to impose this functionality on my c++ code then it will be really helpful. Apart from this App manager is also required which will manage app operation like run/pause/resume/exit/recovery  once installation take place successfully on the device.
App manager I had considered dbus and  systemd but due to negative performance need to drop them. Please advise so that I can move forward on this.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_package_management_systems

Comment: can't it will be achieved programmatically as in embedded linux we don't have space to install those packages.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, may I ask how much space you have available? Sounds like an interesting problem that you have space to install packages, but not enough space for opkg (which takes up 278411 bytes on my system, ignoring 3rd party dependencies like libc6. But it could be shrinked a bit more)